# Como colocar esse tipo de hover?

Tags: html, css, css-hover

O hover que eu quero é esse : http://prntscr.com/i4vr9n

O meu hover está assim: http://prntscr.com/i4vrsk

Meu css e html

```css
html{
    font-family: sans-serif;    
}
header{
    width:100%;
    height:58px;
    background-color: #693;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #487f1e; 
}
 header #logotipo{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position:absolute; 
 }
body{
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background:url(../img/Testing-banner2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;   
    font-size:16px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.div_centralizar{
text-align:center;
}
.logo {
    text-align:center;
 padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
nav#menu {
    display:inline;
}
#menu ul {
    padding:12px;
    margin-left: 240px;
    background-color:#693;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative; 
}
#menu ul li { 
    display: inline; 
}
#menu ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background:#693; 
}   
#menu  li a:hover { 
   background-color:#487F1E;   
}
header #logotipo:hover {
     background-color:#487F1E;
}
#entrar:hover{
    background-color:#487F1E;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2c4d12;
}
.intro{
text-align:center;
}
.container_pagina_inicial{
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#entrar {
    font-size:18px;
    width: 368px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #487f1e;
    background-color: #693;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#email {
    width:368px;
    border-radius:0;   
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
#password {
    width:368px;
    border-radius:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#rodape {
    margin-top: 250px;  
}
p.copyright{
    color:#666;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-top:10px;
}
#subtitulo {
    font-weight:normal;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Ensintech</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-mobile.css">
 
 </head>
 
 <body>

  <header>
          <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                 <nav id="menu">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a class="adm" placeholder href="#">Área administrativa / Docente</a></li>
                       <li><a class="aluno" href="#">Área do Aluno</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>  
         <img id="logotipo" src="img/ensintech.png" alt="Logotipo">        
  </header>

  <div class="container_pagina_inicial">
   <div class="intro">
    <div class="div_centralizar">
     <div class="logo"><img src="img/Egrande.png"></div>
    </div>         
   <p style="font-size:32px">
   Acesso Aluno
   </p>
   <p id="subtitulo">
   Digite seus dados de login para acessar o sistema
   </p>               
   <form id="form_login_pagina_inicial" action="act_login.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form_login_pagina_inicial" target="escondido">
       <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Senha">
    </div>
   </form>        
      <button id="entrar" type="submit" class="form-control">Entrar </button>
      <br>
   <p><a href="#">Esqueci a senha</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
     
  <div class="div_centralizar">            
   <p class="copyright">&copy; 2018 - Ensintech - Todos os direitos reservados</p>
  </div>
            <div id="rodape"></div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu fiz colocando um `line-height: 48px;` no link, esse valor é relativo a altura do menu que é 58px. E ajustei um `padding: 0 12px;` no `<ul>`para o *line-height* não ultrapassar a altura do pai

```
#menu ul {
    padding: 0 12px; /* fiz um ajuste para não ultrapassar a altura do pai */
    margin-left: 240px;
    background-color: #693;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #693;
    line-height: 48px; /* altura do verde escuro no hover */
}
```

**Veja como ficou: *(Execute na "Página Toda" para ver melhor)***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Ensintech</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-mobile.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <style>
    
    html{
    font-family: sans-serif;    
}
header{
    width:100%;
    height:58px;
    background-color: #693;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #487f1e; 
}
 header #logotipo{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position:absolute; 
 }
body{
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background:url(../img/Testing-banner2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;   
    font-size:16px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.div_centralizar{
text-align:center;
}
.logo {
    text-align:center;
 padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
nav#menu {
    display:inline;
}
#menu ul {
    padding: 0 12px;
    margin-left: 240px;
    background-color: #693;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul li { 
    display: inline; 
}
#menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #693;
    line-height: 48px;
}  
#menu  li a:hover { 
   background-color:#487F1E;   
}
header #logotipo:hover {
     background-color:#487F1E;
}
#entrar:hover{
    background-color:#487F1E;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2c4d12;
}
.intro{
text-align:center;
}
.container_pagina_inicial{
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#entrar {
    font-size:18px;
    width: 368px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #487f1e;
    background-color: #693;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#email {
    width:368px;
    border-radius:0;   
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
#password {
    width:368px;
    border-radius:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#rodape {
    margin-top: 250px;  
}
p.copyright{
    color:#666;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-top:10px;
}
#subtitulo {
    font-weight:normal;

}

    </style>
 
 </head>
 
 <body>

  <header>
          <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                 <nav id="menu">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a class="adm" placeholder href="#">Área administrativa / Docente</a></li>
                       <li><a class="aluno" href="#">Área do Aluno</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>  
         <img id="logotipo" src="img/ensintech.png" alt="Logotipo">        
  </header>

  <div class="container_pagina_inicial">
   <div class="intro">
    <div class="div_centralizar">
     <div class="logo"><img src="img/Egrande.png"></div>
    </div>         
   <p style="font-size:32px">
   Acesso Aluno
   </p>
   <p id="subtitulo">
   Digite seus dados de login para acessar o sistema
   </p>               
   <form id="form_login_pagina_inicial" action="act_login.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form_login_pagina_inicial" target="escondido">
       <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Senha">
    </div>
   </form>        
      <button id="entrar" type="submit" class="form-control">Entrar </button>
      <br>
   <p><a href="#">Esqueci a senha</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
     
  <div class="div_centralizar">            
   <p class="copyright">&copy; 2018 - Ensintech - Todos os direitos reservados</p>
  </div>
            <div id="rodape"></div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hugo obrigado novamente, mas eu tenho uma duvida que é igual então vou faze-la aqui, esta vendo aquele logo do Ensintech ao lado esquerdo, eu queria fazer o mesmo tipo de hover nele (http://prntscr.com/i4wuyd)
eu achei que com essas informações eu ia conseguir, mas não estou tendo exito, teria ideia de como fazer ? Melhor eu abrir outra pergunta ou não?

Comment: @FranciscoCarlosCarvalhoJr vou te responder aqui mesmo, só um minuto.

Comment: @FranciscoCarlosCarvalhoJr sem o arquivo do Logo fica difícil acertar os valores, mas vou te explicar aqui no *commente* mesmo: Na classe `.header #logotipo {}` coloque um `line-height: 50px;` e vai ajustando o `margin-top: -50px;` até acertar os valores em PX para ficar perfeito. Eu não gosto de usar valores em PX, mas do jeito que vc montou tudo agora acho que é a melhor opção. Então vai ajustando esse dois valores de PX na Logo que vai dar certo.

Answer (score 1):

É necessário apenas alterar #menu ul li a. Mais especificamente na linha do padding, que antes estava 2px e foi alterado para 20px.

```css
html{
    font-family: sans-serif;    
}
header{
    width:100%;
    height:58px;
    background-color: #693;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #487f1e; 
}
 header #logotipo{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position:absolute; 
 }
body{
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background:url(../img/Testing-banner2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;   
    font-size:16px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.div_centralizar{
text-align:center;
}
.logo {
    text-align:center;
 padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
nav#menu {
    display:inline;
}
#menu ul {
    margin-left: 240px;
    background-color:#693;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative; 
}
#menu ul li { 
    display: inline; 
}
#menu ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background:#693; 
}   
#menu  li a:hover { 
   background-color:#487F1E;   
}
header #logotipo:hover {
     background-color:#487F1E;
}
#entrar:hover{
    background-color:#487F1E;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2c4d12;
}
.intro{
text-align:center;
}
.container_pagina_inicial{
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#entrar {
    font-size:18px;
    width: 368px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #487f1e;
    background-color: #693;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#email {
    width:368px;
    border-radius:0;   
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
#password {
    width:368px;
    border-radius:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#rodape {
    margin-top: 250px;  
}
p.copyright{
    color:#666;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-top:10px;
}
#subtitulo {
    font-weight:normal;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Ensintech</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-mobile.css">
 
 </head>
 
 <body>

  <header>
          <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                 <nav id="menu">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a class="adm" placeholder href="#">Área administrativa / Docente</a></li>
                       <li><a class="aluno" href="#">Área do Aluno</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>  
         <img id="logotipo" src="img/ensintech.png" alt="Logotipo">        
  </header>

  <div class="container_pagina_inicial">
   <div class="intro">
    <div class="div_centralizar">
     <div class="logo"><img src="img/Egrande.png"></div>
    </div>         
   <p style="font-size:32px">
   Acesso Aluno
   </p>
   <p id="subtitulo">
   Digite seus dados de login para acessar o sistema
   </p>               
   <form id="form_login_pagina_inicial" action="act_login.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form_login_pagina_inicial" target="escondido">
       <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Senha">
    </div>
   </form>        
      <button id="entrar" type="submit" class="form-control">Entrar </button>
      <br>
   <p><a href="#">Esqueci a senha</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
     
  <div class="div_centralizar">            
   <p class="copyright">&copy; 2018 - Ensintech - Todos os direitos reservados</p>
  </div>
            <div id="rodape"></div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Referência: [Padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp), [Margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp).